# Making app in Titanium, trying to call function in js file 2 from js file 1

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

Making app in Titanium, i am trying to call a function in another js file i made. i am tring to call function from my index.js. when i do so it cant find it. i think it is a scope issue. in java i would make an object of a class and do object.function(). im not sure how to go about it in JS. Or is it that i have to add my new JS file to a manifest someplace.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ti.include](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium-method-include) method for this. Suppose you have two files, index.js and common.js and you want to call a method `initScreen()` that is defined in common.js. You can call the method inside index.js as follows

```
Ti.include("common.js");  //Write this at the top of your index.js

initScreen(); //As usual
```

You have another option is [require method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require). If you are writing the common.js file as [commonJS module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium), you can use `require method`.

Hope it helped you

Comment: have you given the correct path? The above will work only if both common.js and index.js are in same folder